# DbUnit HSQLDB - invalid schema name: C

Tags: oracle, hsqldb, dbunit

When running a test with the following query, HSQLDB mistakes the table alias as a schema.

```
SELECT c.country_ml2country as CTRY_PK, c.name as CTRY_NAME,
l.name as LANGUAGE_NAME, l.code as LANGUAGE_CODE
FROM country_ml as c, language as l
WHERE c.language(+) = l.id and c.country_ml2country(+) = ?
ORDER BY l.name ASC;
```

Has anyone experienced this before?  If "yes", then what is the fix?

Note that if I change `FROM country_ml as c` to `FROM country_ml as bob`, then the error message changes accordingly to `invalid schema name: BOB`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the non-standard Oracle-style OUTER JOIN syntax, which is specific to Oracle and not supported by other SQL dialects.

```
WHERE c.language(+) = l.id and c.country_ml2country(+) = ?
```

You should use instead the following standard syntax, which Oracle also supports:

```
SELECT c.country_ml2country as CTRY_PK, c.name as CTRY_NAME,
l.name as LANGUAGE_NAME, l.code as LANGUAGE_CODE
FROM country_ml as c RIGHT OUTER JOIN language as l
ON c.language = l.id and c.country_ml2country = ?
ORDER BY l.name ASC
```